# Load PaperScript after jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, paperjs

I would like to draw a paper JS Path as a getJSON callback. My code works, but to render the path I have to hover with my mouse over the `<canvas>`. The Script should work on mobile devices too so I need to get the script works on page load without mouse interaction. Here is my Code:

```js
$(function() {
    paper.install(window);
    var jsonURL = "http://www.domain.com/file.json";

    $.getJSON( jsonURL, function (data){
        paper.setup('myCanvas');
        var point_1_x = data['point1']['x'];
        var point_1_y = data['point1']['y'];
        var point_2_x = data['point1']['x'];
        var point_2_y = data['point1']['y'];

        var myPath = new Path();
        myPath.strokeWidth = 10;
        myPath.strokeColor = 'black';
        myPath.add(new Point(point_1_x,point_1_y));
        myPath.add(new Point(point_2_x,point_2_y));

        paper.PaperScript.load(); // I tried this one
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.25/paper-full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mypaperscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" keepalive="true"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to replicate your issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Stormblessed Here it is: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/shr1k3/oqr1skhu/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

Add paper.view.update(); to the end of the getJSON();